# Length or precision specification 0 is invalid

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have an MFC app which run some SQL statements, and I have run them on several PCs, without any problem.

But, I have met an PC, where when I have tried to run these SQLs, I have encountered an strange error (strange for me, I know SQL a little):

> Length or precision specification 0 is invalid

This error fired on the following SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
  nmytable_ID int IDENTITY (1, 1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  nAsset_ID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES t_asset (nAsset_ID) DEFAULT NULL,
  dtInit date NOT NULL,
  dRest decimal(10, 2) NULL,
  nOdo int NULL,
  sObs varchar(1024) NULL,
  dtDateC datetime2(0) NULL,
  dtDateU datetime2(0) NULL,
  nUserC int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES ntp_appuserx (nAppUserx_ID) DEFAULT NULL,
  nUserU int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES ntp_appuserx (nAppUserx_ID) DEFAULT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT nAsset_ID_mytable UNIQUE (nAsset_ID, dtInit)
)
```

Ok, I have changed `DATETIME2(0)` data type to `DATETIME`, but then I get the following error:

> DATE data type is unknown

There is a question: why this error(s), but on an PC, and not for others ? Is there some local settings which affect my app ? I am using SQL Server 2012.

---

#### Solved

I have tried to create the table on older DB installed on this PC, without to notice that.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Then you can remove the MySQL tag, and replace sql-server-2008 with 2012.

Comment: First, please format your code to make it readable. Secondly, that query will work fine in SQL2012. What do you get if you run this SQL `SELECT @@VERSION`?

Comment: You may be using SQL Server *Management Studio* 2012 but all signs point to you talking to a pre-2008 *server* that doesn't have the `datetime2` nor `date` data types.

Comment: Where I have "MySQL tag" ?

Comment: @flaviu2 You don't because I fixed it

Comment: @ Damien_The_Unbeliever: I cannot use SQL Server management Studio on the PC where I have this issue.

Comment: @DavidG: I cannot run this command, SELECT @@VERSION, at least until I will insert it in my MFC app which run all SQLs.

Comment: @DavidG: if I know that SQL are 2012, it's not enough ? The same version I have installed on others PCs, and I didn't get this error ...

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: I have found an SQL Server 2005 server installed on this PC ... I will uninstall it, and try again, and let you know what I have done. Thank you.

Comment: There was an old SQL Server (2005) on this PC, and I didn't noticed, that was the problem.

Comment: @flaviu2 Please consider either deleting this question or posting an answer to describe the problem and the solution you found, and accept your own answer, so that other people will know that the problem is solved.